# Rails 4 search between created_at dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, search, controller

I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails. I have a feedback model. I want to search the feedback database so that I get results within a selected date range using the created_at field. So I type e.g. "14/04/15" in one box and 16/04/15" and that when I click search, it brings up the @feedbacks between the typed dates, I will later on add jquery date-picker to select the dates in the text fields but I need the thing to function first.

Nothing happens when searched! they all remain as they are. I have 3 feedbacks with created at fields, 13/04/15, 14/04/15, 16/04/15. I type 14/04/15 into the first field and 16/04/15 into the second and hit search. This should bring up feedbacks in the order 14/04/2015, 16/04/15, 13/04/15.

I'm sorry if this has been answered before but nothing seems to help me. I have a form in my feedbacks index:

```
<%= form_tag(feedbacks_path, :method => "get") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :start_date, params[:start_date] %>
<%= text_field_tag :end_date, params[:end_date] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

and this in my feedback controller:

```
 def index
 @feedbacks = Feedback.where("created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date",
 {start_date: params[:start_date], end_date: params[:end_date]})
 @feedbacks = Feedback.where(user_id: current_user)
end
```

URL:

```
 http://localhost:3000/feedbacks?utf8=%E2%9C%93&start_date=14%2F04%2F2015&end_date=16%2F04%2F2015
```

Gemfile:

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'

ruby 2.1.3p242

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Nothing! they all remain as they are. I have 3 feedbacks with created at fields, 13/04/15,  14/04/15,  16/04/15. I type 14/04/15 into the first field and 16/04/15 into the second and hit search. This should bring up feedbacks in the order 14/04/2015, 16/04/15, 13/04/15.

Answer (score 0):

The last statement run is

```
@feedbacks = Feedback.where(user_id: current_user)
```

You're just getting a raw pull of feedbacks for the current user. Your dates aren't used in that statement.

Comment: So how should I add dates in that statement? Ive tried a few daft ways but I cant seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In brief, you should chain your query like this

`def index
 @feedbacks = Feedback.where("created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date", {start_date: params[:start_date], end_date: params[:end_date]})
 @feedbacks = @feedbacks.where(user_id: current_user)
end`

You can even shorten your search using range condition:

`def index
 @feedbacks = Feedback.where(created_at: [params[:start_date]..params[:end_date]])
 @feedbacks = @feedbacks.where(user_id: current_user)
end`